# Cmake error by using pcl library

Tags: c++, cmake

While I followed this tutorial, I stumbled upon error http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer

I installed PCL-1.8.1rc1-AllInOne-msvc2017-win64.exe on this site  https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases/tag/pcl-1.8.1rc1 
 
I made a folder which include "cloud_viewer.cpp" and "CMakeLists.txt" following above tutorial, and used CMake by adding path. But this error came out.

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses PackageName_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable PCL_ROOT is set to:

    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.1 (or C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.8.1)

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Found eigen: C:/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/include  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at C:/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:39 (message):
  common is required but boost was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:354 (pcl_report_not_found)
  C:/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:500 (find_external_library)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

and I don't know how i can fix it.

this is CMakesLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The error says `Could NOT find Boost`. Point CMake to your Boost installation with `BOOST_ROOT` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been through a lot of hoops with the same problem. For me it turns out this was a result of CMake trying to use the *32bit* compiler and that then looked for 32bit dependencies, but PCL has the *64bit* libraries installed with it.

I was able to hunt this down by setting `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` in my CMakeList.txt file. This then revealed the paths that Boost was using and these had "x86" in them.

I got past this problem by using the CMake GUI to (run `cmake-gui .` in the command line where your project is) and then selecting `Visual Studio 2015 Win64` as the Generator. This then generated a Visual Studio project and the 64bit compiler was used, meaning it then looked for the "x64" Boost directory.

Maybe that helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with PCL-1.9.1 and VS2015； I solved this problem by upgrading vs2015 to vs2019

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first Warning:-
set the Environment Variables:  PCL 1.8.1_ROOT

add path: %PCL 1.8.1_ROOT

On the Cmake menu, try "File-> Delete Cache".